# How to hit curl to Kong after applying RBAC authentication

Tags: rbac, kong, kong-plugin

We have authenticated kong with RBAC credentials. Before this, we are able to hit localhost:8001/default/apis?size=100. But after applying RBAC authentication, we are getting the below error

```
{
  "message": "Invalid RBAC credentials. Token or User credentials required"
}
```

Please help with the steps to run this on browser or as curl request.

Answer (score 0):

If you followed the installation instruction, Kong advised seeding [Super Admin token](https://docs.konghq.com/gateway/latest/install-and-run/ubuntu/#seed-super-admin). 
This token can be used with [appropriate header](https://docs.konghq.com/gateway/latest/reference/configuration/#rbac_auth_header) when calling Admin API. 
For example using default header with token value 'password':

```
curl http://kong-ip:8001/ --header 'Kong-Admin-Token: password'
```

If you miss the step of seeding super admin. following [this](https://docs.konghq.com/gateway/latest/admin-api/rbac/examples/#bootstrapping-the-first-rbac-userthe-super-admin) instruction to seed admin token and use it with header from prior reference.